# do we can import sample data of magento in sql server?

Tags: magento-1.9, sample-data

I want to know whether we can import the magento sample data in our SQL Server 2014 and pass the string and db info at the time of installation of magento ?

Comment: Dunno why the downvotes without explanation here's a upvote

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how you are supposed to install the data - ie. BEFORE you install magento. A detailed installation guide is found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-sample

**You must install sample data on the file system and in the database before you install Magento.**

Comment: Is it for SQL Server 2014 ??

Comment: Yes, this is for any SQL server.